# Java handling method with changing return type

Tags: java, casting

I have a method where the return type can be of several known types.
It can return `List<String>` or `List<List<String>>`.
When invoking it I know what kind of return type will be according to the parameters I pass it.
To make thing clear, the method is

```
public List<Object> getValueFromResponseBodyHook(Response res, String key){
    return res.body().jsonPath().getList(key);
}
```

I tried to handle it like this:

```
public boolean validateParameterValueInResponseBodyHook(Response res, String param, String expectedValue, Boolean flat){
    List<List<String>> complex;
    List<String> flat;
    if(flat){
        flat = (List<String>) getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
    }else {
        complex = (List<List<String>>) getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
    }
}
```

However this presents me the following errors:

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>' to 'java.util.List<java.lang.String>'

for this line

```
flat = (List<String>) getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
```

and

> Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'java.util.List<java.lang.Object>' to 'java.util.List<java.util.List<java.lang.String>>'

for this line

```
complex = (List<List<String>>) getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
```

How can I handle this situation correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do this with one method. You are violating type safety. You should instead create two methods, one returning `List<String>` and one returning `List<List<String>>`. Something like this:

```
public List<String> getValueFromResponseBodyHookFlat(Response res, String key){
    return res.body().jsonPath().getList(key);
}

public List<List<String>> getValueFromResponseBodyHookComplex(Response res, String key){
    return res.body().jsonPath().getList(key);
}
```

Then call the appropriate method in your if-test:

```
public boolean validateParameterValueInResponseBodyHook(Response res, String param, String expectedValue, Boolean flat){
    List<List<String>> complex = null;
    List<String> flat = null;
    if (flat) {
        flat = getValueFromResponseBodyHookFlat(res, param);
    } else {
        complex = getValueFromResponseBodyHookComplex(res, param);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: But this is not an overloading! These two methods with different names. This is what I currently have and wanted to work with single method.

Comment: Right, wrong use of the term "overload". Anyway, this is cleaner as it avoids unchecked casts and the violation of type safety. You cannot have an (actual) overload that only differs in its return type.

Comment: OK, since your approach is better according to all the opinions I accept your answer. Also implemented according to it.

Answer (score 1):

An option for this is the keyword `instanceOf`.

```
public boolean validateParameterValueInResponseBodyHook(
   Response res, String param, String expectedValue, Boolean flat){
    List<List<String>> complex;
    List<String> flat;
    List<Object> result = getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
    for (Object listEntry : result)
    {
       if (listEntry instanceOf String) {
         flat = (List<String>) listEntry;
       } else if (listEntry instanceOf List) {
         complex = (List<List<String>>) listEntry;
       }
    
       //What ever you want do to with it
       //...
     }
}
```

Note: You can use this way with `instanceof` to check does the list entries in complex are Strings. Though, the way wich @mastran suggested is little better. Hope it leads you into right direction.

Comment: you don't have to cast `listEntry` but `result`

Comment: Since mastran's approach is the better according to all the opinions I accepted his answer. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer, you taught me pretty ideas, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to solve the problem.
At first, the cleanest way is as marstran mentioned to write two methods.
Anyway:

1. You can change your return type to `List<? extends Object>`.
   Now the cast statements don't lead to a compile error.
2. You can "erase" the generic by saving the result in a non-generic list:

```
List<List<String>> complex;
List<String> flat;
List tmp = getValueFromResponseBodyHook(res,param);
if (flat){
    flat = (List<String>) tmp;
} else {
    complex = (List<List<String>>) tmp;
}
```

3. You can use dynamic generics for your method.
   Note that there's no type safety at compile time.

```
public <T> List<T> getValueFromResponseBodyHook(Response res, String key){
    // maybe need to cast here
    // only works if return type of getList allow cast to List<T> (I don't know the API)
    return res.body().jsonPath().getList(key);
}
```

Comment: Since mastran's approach is the better according to all the opinions I accepted his answer. Anyway thanks a lot for your answer, you taught me several pretty ideas, thanks!